# Javascript recursion trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, recursion

I'm having trouble with javascript recursion. Here is the code

```
_parseJson: function($object, $j_array) {

    for (i = 0; i < $j_array.length; i++) {
        var $el = document_designer.createElement($j_array[i]);
        $object.append($el);
        if ($j_array[i].elements.length > 0) {
            this._parseJson($el, $j_array[i].elements);
        }
    }
}
```

Both functions (`parseJson` and `createElement`) are under the object called "document_designer". Here is the `createElement`

```
createElement: function(n) {
    var $element = $('<' + n['tag'] + '/>');
    document_designer.oi++;
    if (n.id == null) {
        $element.attr('id', '____element' + document_designer.oi);
    }
    document_designer.processElement($element, n); // you may ignore this line
    return $element;
}
```

processElement function is not having problems. You may even ignore that line

```
document_designer._parseJson(document_designer.$preview, json_element)
// $preview is an created object in the `body`
```

and my parent JSON is : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c99c77938e5edf91996e4bb267fd09b1

Root elements are creating and first main's sub childs but other root element's sub elements are not creating

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Root elements are creating and first main's sub childs but other root element's sub elements are not creating

Comment: @ahmetertem, please provide a sample of your json.

Comment: @autoboxer http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c99c77938e5edf91996e4bb267fd09b1

Comment: @autoboxer It's at the link he provided. It's really long.

Comment: Recursive functions need to test when they've reached the base case, so they stop recursing. You have no check for getting to a leaf in the tree.

Comment: @Barmar Yes he does, of no elements it does not recurse.

Comment: But when you get to the bottom there's no `$j_array[i].elements`, so `$j_array[i].elements.length` will get an error.

Comment: Never mind, now I see that the leaf elements have an empty `elements: []`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot the `var` in

```
for (i = 0; i < $j_array.length; i++) {
```

So you are using the same global `i` for all calls

change to:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $j_array.length; i++) {
```

BTW , I like your code.

Comment: Thank you pal. I didn't even think about it can be... I appreciate it

Comment: @ahmetertem  Imagine this happening in a large JS file.Very hard to find.

Comment: I posted just problemmed parts :) My file is already 500+ lines. Thanks again dude